# USB not working

Tags: 18.04, usb, dell, laptop

I have a new Dell Inspiron 3593 i7 with 8gb ram, when I started working on it and needed a mouse it seemed that all the usb ports weren't working for some reason. I looked for drivers that are applicable with Ubuntu but didn't any.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding your Ubuntu version. This may be a power management issue.

Comment: i am using 18.04.4

Answer (score 0):

This may be a power management issue, causing autosuspending of USB ports. To disable this

**I. By installing TLP**

```
 sudo apt install tlp
```

then disable USB auto-suspend by editing

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

set `USB_AUTOSUSPEND` to `0` and restart TLP

```
sudo systemctl restart tlp
```

**II. By manually editing the `/etc/default/grub` file**

[How to disable USB autosuspend on kernel 3.7.10 or above? (on unix.stackexchange.com)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above)